# Printing snippets of a spreadsheet, delimited by a cell containging "$", to pdf

Tags: vba, loops, pdf-generation

between special character to multiple PDF file and save with a naming convention

I am very new to VBA need your help to get a vba code to copy the rows between $ sign to PDF file and save it with specific naming convention.

check the image below

[image]

expected result
1st pdf saved as file1ddmmyyyy 
what 
when 
how
why

22nd file saved as file2ddmmyyyy
yes 
no
correct

many thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Pardon? Please improve your question: 22nd should aparently be 2nd; What PDF-creation technique do you want to use? What did you try so far? How should the PDF look like?

Comment: Apologies should have been 2nd... so far i manually tried to copy the content on new sheet and print as PDF writer and save the document.

Comment: You are new to VBA, but are you new to programming or did you program in other languages before.

Comment: I am new to any programming ....

Comment: trying to find solution for the work i do ...

Answer (score 0):

## Before you start reading the answer, this is not a good answer yet

As explained below, you need a way to generate pdf files that can programmatically be handled well. As I did not have one (My employer does not allow me to install anyting on this PC) I cannot resolve this. I made this a wikky question, do if anyone has the tools feel free to improve this answer.

## Before you start programming

Instead of copying data to another sheet, select the range you want to print and when printing, under Settings, select **Print Selection**.

## Be lazy, ask it to Excel

You can find the technical statements you need bij recording a macro. (To do so, you first need to [make sure the Development tab is visible in the ribon](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG4ZiRpufYAhWNLFAKHd4BA1MQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb608625.aspx&usg=AOvVaw3GtN2cgQenVS3MU52SEjIm).) In my case that gives

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End Sub
```

now, this is no good, as this way to automate

## Improve the recorded code

Essentially, you now have to put the recorded code inside a loop, but usually you have to improve it a bit. (Preferably you improve it a lot, especially if you program for someone else. Otherwise, they will get unexpected results, probably loose data and you will be kept responsible, even if it were them playing arounnd in the spreadsheet while your code is running.)

In this case

- Only refer to the active sheet in the verry beginning
- Do not work with selections, work with ranges.

Beginners write

```
Range("A1:A3").Select
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Range("A5:A9").Select
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

`Range` selects cells on the active sheet. If the user clicks on another tab, your program will start using that other sheet. Instead write

```
Set MySheet = ActiveSheet
MySheet.Range("A1:A3").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
MySheet.Range("A5:A9").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

Define things before you use them. Then the VBA editor will help you with intellisence. Preferably force yourself to do so by with `option explicit` because then the compiler will warn you for typing errors.

```
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
```

## Automate it

```
Option Explicit
Sub print_snippets()
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim FirstCell As Range, OtherCell As Range, LastCell As Range
    Set FirstCell = MySheet.Cells(RowIndex:=2, ColumnIndex:=1)
    Set OtherCell = FirstCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1)

    Do While Not IsEmpty(OtherCell.Value)
        If OtherCell.Value = "$" Then
            Set LastCell = OtherCell.Offset(RowOffset:=-1)
            Range(FirstCell, LastCell).PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

            Set FirstCell = OtherCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
            Set OtherCell = FirstCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        Else
            Set OtherCell = OtherCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        End If
    Loop        
End Sub
```

Comment: ` Sub PDFActiveSheet()
'for Excel 2010 and later
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

`

Comment: 'code`'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")`code`

Comment: `code`'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub`code`

Comment: That is why I made it a community wiki. You can edit the code yourself now.